# Steam stops downloading when my PC is locked

Tags: steam, windows-10

When I lock my computer, steam stops downloading updates. For example today, I came in the evening and there was an update for a game that I play. I could see "Time initiated" to be 14:30, yet nothing was downloaded and it was just starting. I could reproduce this. If I locked my PC and came back 10 mins later, the download speed graph clearly indicated no download is happening.

Is there some settings in Windows 10 or Steam that affects this? I can verify that the computer does not disconnect when locked - other download clients download even when locked and I can connect via team viewer.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't able to replicate this (I started a download, made note of the progress, came back a few minutes later, and the download was still in progress with no blips) Did your PC go to sleep sometime with that 10 mins? If so, I'd check your PC's power settings. I believe downloads pause if the PC goes to sleep.

Comment: Yeah agree with above. Check your settings to see what your PC does after a while. Does it go to sleep when it's locked? If so just set it to do Do Nothing.

Comment: And see if your network adaptors have 'Allow the computer to turn off this device' enabled in Device Manager.

Comment: @Joachim I asked a friend, had the same problem you decribe, fixed you as you described. I am now thinking this may have been causing other issues too.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved!

Answer (score 4):

A friend had a same problem. I asked him if it's still happening and he said that he found out windows was allowed to turn off the network adapter. This probably only applies to wireless adapters, especially USB ones.

How to fix that:

1. Go to `devmgmt.msc`
2. Find the adapter under *Network adapters*
3. Uncheck the checkbox that is checked on this image: 
     [image]

This is not steam specific. I will test that no other problems happen.

If you found another issue specifically in steam, please post another answer, it can help other people!